# Better way of calling 'call' redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Using the example from react-boiler-plate:

```
const response = yield call(() => axios.get(requestURL));
```

Is there a better way to call axios.get, what if i have axios.post? How can I clean this up a bit without having to do '() =>' just to force it into a function.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to unit test using simple deep equals assertions you could do

```
const response = yield call([axios, 'get'], requestUrl)

const response = yield call([axios, axios.get], requestUrl)
```

This allows you to avoid creation of anonymous lambda on every call.

[Docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fnname-args)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I was wondering if you could create a function that takes a function as an argument and return the function for yield call because the call method requires a function.

Comment: @calpang Could you add a pseudo code of the way you want to use this function?

Comment: I figured it out, i wasn't too happy with anonymous function there. After reading the docs more carefully I figured that i could do this:

const response = yield call(axios.get, requestURL);

passing the actual function, and the params in the second argument. 

thanks for your help